# Block emails with large number of recipients of same domain

Tags: bcc, spamassassin, exim4

I have a mailserver with exim4 and spamassassin installed.

We have a problem of (internal) spam to a large number of mailinglists, coming from a few  users (which we cannot just educate or block for multiple reasons)

Is there a way to block emails to which an unreasonable amount go to the same domain (e.g. 10) to force these users to BCC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in SpamAssassin.  I'm not as much an exim expert, but iirc exim can do this as well (though it may have a hard recipient limitation that is agnostic to To/Cc vs Bcc).

This should do it:

```
header   DTECH_TEN_TOCC_IN_SAME_DOM  ToCc =~ /(\@[^,>;]{3,99}[a-z]\b)(?:[^\@.-][^\@]{0,99}\1){10}(?![.-])/
describe DTECH_TEN_TOCC_IN_SAME_DOM  Ten consecutive recipients have the same domain
```

As I've written it, this only catches ten *consecutive* recipients with the same domain, which must all be in the same header (`ToCc` means either To xor Cc; it does not merge the headers).  If you change the third character class from `[^\@]{0,99}` to `.{0,999}` to match any character over a longer period of time, the rule will be good for more than just consecutively listed addresses, **but note** that this would make the regex far more expensive to compute.

You also have to make sure that SpamAssassin is looking at your internal and outbound mail, which is nonstandard.  Finally, you'll have to score the rule.  Please test copiously before you do that.  Especially since this is *not* a spam rule (it will hit more non-spam than spam; consider a similar rule with testing stats: [__TO_MANY](http://ruleqa.spamassassin.org/?rule=__TO_MANY)).

You will not, however, be able to tell users *why* the message was rejected.  An SMTP reject (e.g. from Exim) can have a custom "why this was rejected" prompt, which is highly useful for policing attachment sizes or even informing users that they're sending too much mail (perhaps they are infected).  You can configure Exim to run SA at SMTP time (e.g. [sa-exim](http://marc.merlins.org/linux/exim/sa.html)), but then every spam rejection would have the same message to the end user.  The other option would be to accept the message and then bounce it back, including the SpamAssassin rule hits.  Be very very careful with that approach as it often leads to [backscatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_spam).